# change mac appearance color (from blue and graphite)

Tags: macos, mac, colors, user-interface

The choice of either Blue or Graphite in Appearance looks so poor and sad.
I am running OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 but the same ever boring colors have been in all versions.

Screenshot: [image: Appearance Color Selector]

is there ANY way I can change it? (anything goes)

P.S.: it's a computer from work I am stuck with so please don't suggest "get another laptop or another OS"

Answer (score 3):

macOS 10.14 (Mojave) brings with it eight accent color choices (along with Dark appearance for all of them).

You’ll find them all in System Preferences.
[image: macOS Mojave > System Preferences > General]

Next challenge: Find a `defaults` key that’ll let us set it to colors beyond the default eight.

Comment: Found it. The key is `AppleAccentColor` but the options are simply indexed by [preset integers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51695756/1489243). However `defaults write -g AppleAccentColor` doesn't seem to do anything, so I can't test anything out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Users have been stuck with Blue or Graphite for over 10 years.  They got rid of every other color since the death of the "flavored" iMacs of the early 2000s (remember those?).

Anyway, this is just an arbitrary decision they made long ago and there's not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for same functionality this afternoon and found the information in the below links which suggests an OS X 10.10 compatible version of Flavours 2 is imminent.  I have not used it yet and do not necessarily endorse it but seems relevant to OP question.

http://flavours.interacto.net/

Also, the previous answers seems to predate availability of the sneak peak version released only a couple of days ago 07/05/15.

https://rink.hockeyapp.net/apps/251163d75d6ed8f4f639239fb7e5a545

Comment: Thanks dude it's the only thing I found so far as well. Any others?

Comment: No that's all I've found  The current UI look & feel is the reason I've not taken the plunge & bought a Mac just yet.  The current dark mode doesn't go far enough for me.  This looks promising though.

Comment: All well and great, but ONLY works on macOS 10.10.  I have 10.11, no go.

Answer (score 0):

Apple is strict regarding this option but there are some applications that you can install to run themes on your mac.

Another option is to enable Dark Mode:

> _ Launch System Preferences from your Applications folder.
>
> _ Click on General in the top-left corner of the preferences pane.
>
> _ Check the box next to "Use dark menu bar and Dock" just below the Appearance option.

Comment: Nobody said it's gonna be easy but there has to be a way. Not interested in dark mode, thanks.

Comment: Which apps BTW ???

Comment: check this site  but you have to pay      http://flavours.interacto.net/

Comment: "Unsupported version (10.10.3). Your current OS X version is not supported by this version of Flavours™. You won't be able to use Flavours™ for now."